# How can we add a new action (like Edit & Delete) for each record on the standard list page (Salesforce Classic)

Tags: list, action, salesforce-classic

How can we add a new action (like *Edit & Delete*) for each record on the standard list page (Salesforce Classic)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. What you can is:-

Customize the buttons on the list view i.e in your case, you can add a button near the new program button.

[image]

**Add or remove Custom buttons In Aloha**

1. For standard objects

   i.    From Setup, click Customize | then click the object you want to modify | click Search Layouts.
2. For custom objects

   i.    From Setup, click Create | then click Objects.

   ii.   Click one of the custom objects in the list.

   iii.  Scroll down to the "Search Layouts" section.
3. Click Edit next to the List View layout
4. Highlight the values and click on the Add or Remove button to toggle the visibility of the button on the layout.
5. Click Save.

Reference:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000182076&type=1

Comment: I have seen orgs where someone added there more fields... I will look for example but I do remeber doing that.