# Is there a way to add New links to List Views along with existing links?

Tags: configuration, list-view, quickaction, kanban

I would like to know if there is a way to add a new link to List view records along with existing links like Edit | Delete | Change Owner?

Comment: check this:- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235850/how-can-we-add-a-new-action-like-edit-delete-for-each-record-on-the-standard/235860#235860

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Delete, change owner are Salesforce provided links. If user's profile has Edit or Delete Access at Object level then those links will be shown.

Salesforce doesn't allow us to create custom link beside those. Though, you can create custom link only on record detail page.

Refer this

[image: Custom link]

Comment: You can add list view buttons, though, too.